# What’s the message format for sending SNS notifications using the iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I’m trying to send a push notification using Amazon SNS. This is how I create the message body:

```
NSDictionary *message = @{
    @"APNS_SANDBOX" : @{@"aps" : @{@"alert": @"foo"}},
    @"default" : @"bar"
};
NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:message options:0 error:NULL];
NSString messageBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The notification arrives at the destination device, but the message is “bar”, not “foo”. In other words, the default transport is used, not the APNS-specific one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catch is that the value for a given transport key is supposed to be an already serialized JSON string:

```
NSDictionary *message = @{
    @"APNS_SANDBOX" : @"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"foo\"}}",
    @"default" : @"bar"
};
```

This works fine.